# How Do I Make Fast Ship Contrails/Wake

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I am working on a project involving boats. It looks really plain right now, but I wanted to add some contrails behind the boat to make the scene look better. Something like in the examples but smaller

I need something fast like a shader or something instead of a fluid sim or dynamic paint. Is there any way to do this?

I'll drop some pictures of an example and my scene.
[image: My Scene]

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Comment: You said "fluid sim" and "dynamic" - does this mean you need the wake to "move" with the boat?

Comment: These tutorials seem fine, they use Dynamic Paint though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smArCTzxGpE ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd3hkftRaHA

Comment: Also you can buy animated textures like in this page: https://www.shutterstock.com/fr/video/search/boat-foam